# How to compare data of two services, which should do the same?

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing, microservices

I am extracting a rest microservice out of a rest monolithic application. When everything is correct, they should do the same database interactions... Both are java (or kotlin) applications using Spring (Boot).

Therefore I want to do the following:
I want to send specific test data to the endpoints of both systems and then compare which data is in the database. After every interaction the data needs to be the same.

Does anybody know how to compare the data? Maybe there is a tool, a framework or whatever... Do I need to do this manually? Are there any tips or tricks?

I already searched the web for this, but maybe I didn't use the correct search phrases or so.

Best regards & thanks in advance!

---

Edit: I do NOT need to migrate data from one database to the other

Comment: Are the applications also exposing the data stored in their respective databases? If thats the case then something like gatling.io or a well written postman set of tests could validate the data once posted in the endpoints of the applications.

Comment: I want to share my experience with you: first one is when I search for some solution and it doesn't exist the first thing that come to my mind is that I'm looking for the wrong one. Second couldn't you mock the database layer and just  compare those sample data that are written in your language?

Comment: @Billatron thank you for this idea. Most data are also exposed by the application, but not all of them. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @tashkhisi this is a good idea. This should be possible. Thank you very much!